# Is this crack something that my builder should fix?

Tags: concrete, slab

The house was built about a year ago. There is crack along the cut and some more on the slab in the garage, which is the first floor of my townhouse.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That crack is typical of concrete. There is just minor separation with no shifting along the 2 sections.

The groove formed in the adjoining surface is a "control joint". It is there to control how a large concrete mass cracks so it occurs in a way that is not so unsightly. According to the picture, it is doing its' job very well.